# flutter firebase data update

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
`Future<void> updateData(bool durum) {
    var ref= _firestore
        .collection("Person")
        .doc(firebaseUser?.uid)
        .collection("Kelimeler")
        .doc()
        .update({
      "durum":durum,
    },);

    return ref;
  }`
```

I wrote a data update function. Since the data is nested in my database, I need to update the innermost data, but if I write it in the doc() part of the code, the text is not accepted.

Comment: Can you add your Firebase data, json? It will be easier for anyone to help yiou

Comment: you must adding doc id before update method.

```
var ref= _firestore
        .collection("Person")
        .doc(firebaseUser?.uid)
        .collection("Kelimeler")
        .doc(**DOC_ID**)
        .update({
      "durum":durum,
    },);
```